# Flask 2.0 async - RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: flask, python-asyncio, flask-restful

Getting this on accessing `get_features` POST api

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

```
@api_v1.route('/get_features', methods=['POST'])
async def get_features():
    results = []
    with app.app_context():
        inputs = request.json
        responses = await get_features_for_all(inputs)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(response)
        return jsonify({'result': results})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `with app.app_context():` line since you are already in a context (the flask route).